# Насколько правильно использовать такой вариант наследования классов (композиция)?

Tags: php

Есть классы `update`, `request`, `insert` и они находятся в разных файлах. мне нужно, допустим в классе `products` методы из класса `requset` и `insert`. сейчас я могу только в классе `produtcs` сделать `extends` класса `request` но не могу получить методы класса `insert`

Можно использовать композицию

```
private $requestData; 
private $updateData;
private $insertData;

public function __construct() {
    $this->requestData = new \core\classes\db_wrapper\request;
    $this->updateData = new \core\classes\db_wrapper\update;
    $this->insertData = new \core\classes\db_wrapper\insert;
}
```

Насколько это правильно и есть ли другие варианты ?

Или (скорее всего архитектура изначально не верная)

p.s учусь ООП

upd

у меня есть класс products

```
class Products extends \core\classes\db_wrapper\request {
        
    //__construct
    
    // получить товар по id 
    public function getById(int $int) {
        // тут можно написать обычный sql

        //но у меня есть обертка для sql которая находится в классе request
        return $this->request([
            'table_name' => 'products',
            'col_list' => '*',
            'base_query' => ' WHERE product_id = :id ',
            'query' => [
                'query' => '...',
                'joins' => '...',
                'order' => '...',
                'limit' => '...',
            ],
            'bindList' => [
                ':id' => $id
            ]
        ])->first()->get();
    }


    public function editProducts(array $arr) {
        // тут также могу сделать сдандартный sql 

        // но мне нужно использовать методы класса update и как в примере выше изменить данные товара
    }
        
}
```

для этого мне нужно наследовать два класса, вопрос в этом и был как мне наследовать внутри класса два других класса

Comment: У меня такой вопрос: "а зачем" так делать?

Comment: @YaMus В классе insert и requst у меня своя обертка для sql достаточно удобная. 

в классе products например есть метод get_porducts_by_id(int $id) внутри этого метода я используя метод requst делаю запрос в базу данных
так же есть метод add_products добавляю через метод insert. Можно в самом методе класса products писать sql без наследования и оберток для  и проблема решается. Но мне интересно (так-как я учусь) возможно ли это сделать как-то еще не используя композицию . и правильно ли использовать ее

Comment: Композицию можно использовать там, где это уместно......Использовать композицию методов от БД в классе Продукты - это что-то станное......... Используй просто методы класса Db, где есть все нужные методы для работы БД и всё..

Comment: Т.е. есть у тебя метод `getById` ну и пиши внутри `Db::get(...)`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский тогда мне метод get нужно сделать static ?

Comment: Не обязательно. Но можно. Суть сообщения была же не в этом

Comment: @АлексейШиманский скорее всего я не ясно объяснил свою проблему попробую дополнить вопрос

Comment: *"но у меня есть обертка для sql которая находится в классе request"*  --- используй просто `return new request(...)`. А вообще 1) называть выборку `SELECT`  как `request` - некорректно. Да и делать отдельные классы на каждый вид запроса нет смысла. Почему не иметь один цельный класс `DB` со всеми необходимыми методами? И далее в других классах использовать эти самые методы этого класса

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я сначало так и сделал, но потом решил, что дополняя класс методами выборки и тд класс превратится в кашу, но скорее всего я так и сделаю как Вы и сказали, доверюсь вашему опыту

Comment: @АлексейШиманский самый оптимальный вариант насколько я понял использовать трейты. В файле db.php написать трейты для get, insert, update и через и в классе использовать use. Потом наследовать один класс db

Comment: *"класс превратится в кашу"* --- а что, нужно миллион выборок? В классе будет select, update, insert, delete. Вроде не так уж и много.

Comment: *"написать трейты для get, insert, update"*  --- можно, если это общие методы для различных типов БД. И тогда если будет например DBPostgres и DBMysql то там должна быть конкретная реализация для конкретных субд........но в целом, очень странное желание на каждый метод делать трейт.......для чего? какая цель? чтобы класс не был большой? хм....а так будет тыща мелких классов. и в чём прикол?